# Add category to post meta

Tags: php, post-meta

I'm trying to add the category to the post-meta.php file so the blog page will not only show the author and date, but also the category for each post. However, I can't seem to find any correct way to do so. The current code is the following:

```
<span class="post-meta">
<?php
$author = "<a href='" . esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ) . "'>" . esc_html( get_the_author() ) . "</a>";
$date   = "<a href='" . esc_url( get_month_link( get_the_date( 'Y' ), get_the_date( 'n' ) ) ) . "'>" . date_i18n( get_option( 'date_format' ), strtotime( get_the_date( 'r' ) ) ) . "</a>";
?>
<?php printf( _x( 'Published by %1$s on %2$s', 'This blog post was published by some author on some date', 'author' ), $author, $date ); ?>
```

Could someone please help me do this? Thanks!

Comment: you just want to get and show the category of a post?

Answer (score 1):

you can use `get_the_category_list()` it will show a list of the categories of the post, you can also use `get_the_category()` it will return an array, you can iterate it to format it, you can find examples [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/).

Answer (score 0):

`<?php  foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { ?>
  <a href="<?php echo $category->name; ?>"><?php echo $category->name; ?></a>`

use `echo $category->name` to get category name Or use `echo $category->category_nicename` to get class name